# Template output evaluation skipped

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

If I try to deploy my arm Template (Something like this)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {
     "AAS": "TestAAS",
     "AFU": "TestAFU",    
},
  "resources": [
//define some resource here
],
  "outputs": {
"asName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('AAS')]"
    },
    "azureFunctionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('AFU')]"
    }}
}
```

if for any reason this isn't going well, I can not read output in Powershell. and I get the following message:

```
Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details
```

what should I do so that the output parameters are passed to powershell script despite faulty execution

My Powershell code:

```
 //Standard PowerShell code for Deploying ARM Template
 try 
  {

 Stop-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $deployment.Outputs.item("AFU").value
 Suspend-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -Name $deployment.Outputs.item("AAS").value -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
   }
 catch 
  {
        Write-Host "error here"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do anything here. Outputs are only being generated if there were no errors in the ARM Template flow. So you need your ARM Template to succeed to be able to retrieve those (doesn't matter which tool you use, API behind those is always the same one).